# Disable sandbox mode for facebook app via api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if there is an (undocumented?) field/property in graph api I can use to disable sandbox mode for an app?

I have checked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ and googled my eyeballs sore, but can't find anything, is this only available from the app settings panel on developers.facebook.com/apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no undocumented/documented property for this. You must enable/disable manually from your app settings.

Comment: argh... annoying... hoped for a different answer, but thanks, at least I wont have to keep trying to figure it out :)